# asp.net fileupload Control filename issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In asp.net fileupload control whenever we enter huge filename like 
"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbCopykjfasgfsbgjgbjhbjsdfhgvbjldsfsdfgdfgsdfgdsgdgdsfgsfdsgsddsfgfgsdgffffffffffffffffffffffffffaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahgbjfdshgbjjfdshgbjdsgbjsdhbgsdhfgbsdhbgjsbdghbsdlfjg.pdf"

my entire stylesheet is getting disturbed i need to restrict the filename length or style sheet should be fixed in that content.. Please help

Comment: can u share your code

Answer (score 0):

When the file is uploaded you can check the name length and either tell the user it is too long or rename it yourself

Comment: when user selects the file my stylesheet is getting disturbed.. how can i restrict that